# Can CMake intelligently support GCC "-include" directive

Tags: eclipse, cmake

Porting a collection of IAR Embedded Workbench projects to CMake/GCC.

The IAR projects make use of "preinclude headers" (header files that are automatically included in every source file in the project without being explicitly pulled in with a #include statement - not to be confused with precompiled headers).  These map nicely to the GCC "-include " directive and I can manually implement it in my CMakeList.txt file as follows

```
set(PREINCLUDE_FILE "${PROJ_BASE_DIR}/some-path/preinclude.h")

...

if (PREINCLUDE_FILE)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -include ${PREINCLUDE_FILE}")
endif()
```

and generate a makefile that builds OK.  However when I use CMake to generate an Eclipse project there is no consideration given to the preinclude file(s).

In my case the preinclude contains several preprocessor definitions that effectively drive the configuration of the rest of the system during compilation - without them the Eclipse CDT Indexer does not get all the definitions required to make sense of the codebase and requires additional manual configuration before it will do anything useful.

Is there any way to automate any of this from the CMakeList.txt file?

Comment: Can you give an example of how the `preinclude.h` looks like? Just from reading your description a solution may be to tranfer those preprocessor definitions to CMake's [`add_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_definitions.html) command.

Comment: Yes, in this particular case it is just a handful of simple preprocessor definitions - I was wondering if CMake had a "proper" mechanism to deal with a more general case of a preinclude header with arbitrary content.

Comment: If I look at [Tests/ForceInclude/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Tests/ForceInclude/CMakeLists.txt) I would say, no there is no generic way in CMake for handling forced includes.

Comment: I tried target_compile_definitions() (rather than add_definitions(), as my CMakeList.txt is not in the workspace root)  to pass the preprocessor defines from the preinclude file to CMake, and while the defines in question are correctly included in the "C" build, there is no sign of them in the generated Eclipse .project/.cproject files and I am no closer to an Eclipse CDT Indexer configured ready-to-go from the CMake project generation.

Is this a CMake bug/omission?

Comment: Raised https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=15925 regarding definitions specified with target_compile_definitions() not ending up in Eclipse CDT project file